# UNIX shell scripting - if else condition

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement

**I am making a trivia game in UNIX with VoiceOver Utility on Mac OS X.  My shell script is below.  Why won't my if-else condition work?  Any ideas?**

```
#!/bin/sh
clear

echo "Hey Gamers! Thanks for playing MARVEL COMICS"

echo "What is your super hero name?"
say -v Victoria "What is your super hero name?"
read name

echo "$name, sounds like a pretty epic hero."
say -v Victoria "$name, sounds like a pretty epic hero."

echo "See if you know the names of other epic heroes from Marvel Comics."
say -v Victoria "See if you know the names of other epic heroes from Marvel Comics."


echo "#1. World War 2 Veteran, Steve Rogers, is also known by what super hero name?"
say -v Victoria "World War 2 Veteran, Steve Rogers, is also known by what super hero name?"
read answer1

if [$answer1 = "captain america"]
 then
echo "CORRECT. - Steve Rogers is Captain America."
say -v Victoria "Correct. Steve Rogers is Captain America.";

else
echo "INCORRECT. - Steve Rogers is Captain America"
say -v Victoria "Incorrect. Steve Rogers is Captain America"
fi
```

Comment: test it with `if [ "$answer1" = "captain america" ]` (look at the spaces)

Comment: Thanks, higuaro.  Unfortunately, the double quote method does not fix the program.

Comment: Notice the space after the `[`.  `[` is a command, but it is very unlikely that the value of `$answer1` is such that `[$answer1` is a valid command.  You want `"$answer1"` to be the first argument to the command `[`, so you need to insert a space after the `[`.  This is much clearer if you use `test` instead of `[`.

Comment: Thanks so much, William Pursell :) we have a functioning game!  Thanks again, higuaro!

Comment: Higuaro, you were right about the spaces in the brackets and spaces between the variable's string value.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that you're writing almost all those strings out twice worry you?  It should!  (Does the inconsistency of the printing the opening message only, not saying it, worry you?  I'm not sure if it should.)  Create a function: `echo_say() { echo "$*"; say -v Victoria "$*"; }` and use it (e.g. replace two lines with `echo_say "What is your super hero name?"`).  And, just for once, `"$*"` is probably correct here; very often, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Higuaro & William Pursell for your help!

Here's my UNIX shell - trivia game for Mac OS X!

```
#!/bin/sh
clear

echo "Hey Gamers! Thanks for playing MARVEL COMICS"

echo "What is your super hero name?"
say -v Victoria "What is your super hero name?"
read name

echo "$name, sounds like a pretty epic hero."
say -v Victoria "$name, sounds like a pretty epic hero."

echo "See if you know the names of other epic heroes from Marvel Comics."
say -v Victoria "See if you know the names of other epic heroes from Marvel Comics."


echo "#1. World War 2 Veteran, Steve Rogers, is also known by Captain (what)?"
say -v Victoria "World War 2 Veteran, Steve Rogers, is also known by Captain what?"
read answer1

if [ $answer1 = "america" ]
 then
echo "CORRECT. - Steve Rogers is Captain America."
say -v Victoria "Correct. Steve Rogers is Captain America.";

else
echo "INCORRECT. - Steve Rogers is Captain America"
say -v Victoria "Incorrect. Steve Rogers is Captain America"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

If bash syntax is:

`if [ expression 1 ]
then
   Statement(s) to be executed if expression 1 is true
else
   Statement(s) to be executed if expression 1 is false
fi`

So try:

`if [$answer1 = "captain america"]
then
    echo "CORRECT. - Steve Rogers is Captain America."
    say -v Victoria "Correct. Steve Rogers is Captain America.";
else
    echo "INCORRECT. - Steve Rogers is Captain America"
    say -v Victoria "Incorrect. Steve Rogers is Captain America"
fi`

Comment: Thanks, Nathan.  Unfortunately, that method does not work for the program.